# how to reverse a string that is identified as an id in javascript?

Tags: javascript

HTML file:

```
Dear <span id="salutation">Name</span>;

<p>

  It has come to our attention that your invoice <span id="invoice">ID</span>

  has yet to be paid. It has now been <span id="time">some time</span> since

  you received <span id="item">the material</span> from Evil Incorporated. Please

  remit payment immediately. <span id="threaten"></span>

</p>

  Yours sincerely,<br>

<br>

<br>

  J. Smith, Accounting

<div id="buttons">
```

Format

Clear

THE QUESTION

=> write a function reverse(tag) that takes one string as argument(tag). tag is the id of an elements in HTML. This function should reverse the innerHTML value associated with the id provided. if the element does not exist in the HTML document then your program should display and alert and do nothing. Test your code by defining the format() function to call reverse ('salutation').
=> write a function clearit() that adds a button "print" to the id='buttons'. This print should display it as print, and should have onclick attribute that refers to a function print() 
=> write a function print() that displays and alert with the text "print called' to demonstrate that the code above works properly.

Comment: There are people here who do other peoples homework. I'm one of them. But you have to show your own efforts to solve the problem, even the tiniest bit would suffice but just C&P your assignment is a bit too ...uhm...audacious, even for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple...

```
function reverse(tag) {
  var el = document.getElementById(tag);
  if(!el) {
    return alert('nope');
  }
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: thanks i have another question, lets say i have to buttons one if "format" and the second is "clear" i want when i press the button "clear" to flip with format. so lets say the button order is format then clear i want it to be clear then format